# Select data from query1 where option = and != together

Tags: sql, oracle, join

help me please.

I having result set (table). To get the this first result set, I make a selection with three joins. To get all the necessary characteristics of the goods ( 05_A and 05_B and some descriptions)

We can see stock items.

for example:

```
artid | warehousetype 
001   | 05_A
001   | 05_B
002   | 05_A
```

I need to select all artid where warehouse type in 05_A and not in 05_B (ex. 002)

I'm try:
`select * from table where warehousetype like 05_A and warehousetype not like 05_A` - it's not work.

I'm try

```
select * from table where warehousetype like 05_A
MINUS
select * from table where warehousetype like 05_B
```

it's works but i'm see all stock w\o 05_B, but need see only artid where whtype = 05_A and not 05_B

How do make my report?

Comment: As the parameter is a string, you need to put quotation marks: 
select * from table where warehousetype like '05_A'
and warehousetype not like '05_B'

Comment: "*it's works but i'm see all stock w\o 05_B, but need see only artid where whtype = 05_A and not 05_B*" - Can you explain further? Double check if it works as expected, in the demo of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the NOT EXISTS clause along with a subquery to achieve the desired result.

```
SELECT artid
FROM table
WHERE warehousetype = '05_A'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT artid
    FROM table table2
    WHERE warehousetype = '05_B'
    AND table.artid = table2.artid
);
```

You can also use a JOIN with a negation condition on the joined table to get the same result.

```
SELECT t1.artid
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2 on t1.artid = t2.artid and t2.warehousetype = '05_B'
WHERE t1.warehousetype = '05_A'
AND t2.artid is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Oracle's [`MINUS`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/The-UNION-ALL-INTERSECT-MINUS-Operators.html#GUID-B64FE747-586E-4513-945F-80CB197125EE) operator, to subtract all "*artid*" values that have '05_B' from all records that have '05_A'.

```
SELECT artid FROM tab WHERE warehousetype = '05_A'
MINUS
SELECT artid FROM tab WHERE warehousetype IN ('05_B')
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/L1swOjcU).

Answer (score 0):

With your sample data ...

| ARTID | WAREHOUSETYPE |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 05_A |
| 001 | 05_B |
| 002 | 05_A |

...you could use LISTAGG analytic function to get a list of warehouse types per ARTID:

```sql
SELECT  ARTID, WAREHOUSETYPE,
        LISTAGG(WAREHOUSETYPE, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By WAREHOUSETYPE) OVER(Partition By ARTID)  "WH_LIST"
FROM    tbl
```

| ARTID | WAREHOUSETYPE | WH_LIST |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 05_A | 05_A, 05_B |
| 001 | 05_B | 05_A, 05_B |
| 002 | 05_A | 05_A |

With this WH_LIST you can use LIKE and NOT LIKE ...

```sql
SELECT    ARTID, WAREHOUSETYPE
FROM    ( SELECT    ARTID, WAREHOUSETYPE,
                    LISTAGG(WAREHOUSETYPE, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By WAREHOUSETYPE) OVER(Partition By ARTID)  "WH_LIST"
          FROM      tbl )
WHERE WH_LIST LIKE '%05_A%' And WH_LIST NOT LIKE '%05_B%'
```

Result:

| ARTID | WAREHOUSETYPE |
| --- | --- |
| 002 | 05_A |

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest possible way to do this. In the inner query you get every art id with warehouse '05_B' with it. Then you exclude all those ids from the list of ids where warehousetype '05_A' matches with.

```
SELECT artid FROM table
WHERE warehousetype = '05_A' AND artid
NOT IN(
    SELECT artid
    FROM table
    WHERE warehousetype = '05_B'
);
```

I did not test it so please correct if there is any syntax issues or whatsoever. Except for that its should be working perfectly.